# What can we say about the infinite product $\prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - x/n^p)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, analysis, reference-request, infinite-product

Consider the infinite product

$$P(x,p) = \prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - \dfrac{x}{n^p})$$

where $x \geq 0$ and $p \geq 0$.

Does it have a closed form?

Are there general values for $x, p$ such that this infinite product goes to $0$, $\infty$ or some finite number?

Comment: If $p=2$, it is the infinite product for $\frac{\sin(\pi \sqrt x)}{\pi \sqrt x}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the general [formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html) for integer $p\geq 2$ (Prudnikov et al. 1986, p. 754)

$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{z^p}{k^p}\right)=-\frac{1}{z^p}\prod_{k=0}^{p-1} \frac{1}{\Gamma(-e^{2\pi ik/p}z)}.$$

Yours is the above evaluated at $z=x^{1/p}$

Comment: Full reference:  Prudnikov, A. P.; Brychkov, Yu. A.; and Marichev, O. I. "Infinite Products." §6.2 in Integrals and Series, Vol. 1: Elementary Functions. New York: Gordon & Breach, pp. 753-757, 1986

Comment: Does this come from $n$th term-extracting out of the  Weierstrass product of $\Gamma$?